# Filemaker - Automatically log into calendar.sunrise.am

Tags: javascript, webview, calendar, filemaker

I'm not really that experienced in this area but I have the following problem:

I'm creating a Filemaker solution which is linked to Google Calendar. It works really well so far. Now what I'd like to do is to actually have a visible calendar within my solution. I can already link filemaker scripts to my Google Cals entries, so all I need now is a way to view the actual calendar and insert entries. There are many ways to accomplish this. The most elegant solution I've come across is Seedcode.

Since none of these solutions though are cheap (they cost 1000 bucks at least) and aren't even on par with the actual Google Calendar or Sunrise calendar - a portal to Google Cal. I thought that it would be much better to just include https://calendar.sunrise.am/ in a webview in filemaker. Thus my solution would have the same functionality as Seedcode, with a much more sophisticated UI.

My dilemma now is that I have to login to Sunrise within Filemaker's webview. When I attempt to login, a popup of the system's standard browser (Internet explorer) comes up. After logging in through the popup, the webview still remains on the same login page (loading for ever)...

Now to my question. Is it possible to inject the login submit through javascript or something similar? Or is there any other way to accomplish this? I don't think that it supports cookies; although I'm not really sure how FM's webview works.

I'm really experienced with C++/Python. But as you may have noticed, I'm quite a noob in regards to html etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is a really simple and free Filemaker calendar example here: 
http://forums.filemaker.com/posts/1bc6721dbc

It's easy to integrate into your current solution if in this order you:
1) Copy/paste the tables to your database, 
2) Copy/paste the scripts
3) Copy/paste the calendar layout
4) Re-point the date relationship to your 'events' so that your events show on the calendar.